# Calculate most common value across 1 <-> 1..n | 0..N <-> 1 in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following setup:

- Message 1..N <-> 1 Topic
- Message 0..N <-> 1 Mood

Tables:

```
Message
| id
| text
| mood_id
| topic_id

Topic
| id
| title

Mood
| id
| title
```

Messages have to be posted to a particular topic. When posting a message to a topic, the user can attach his mood how he feels when writing that message to the message itself.

I am trying to write a query which does the following:

- Aggregate the amount of messages for each topic
- Find the most used mood for each topic

The optimal output would be a list of something like this:

```
| topic.id
| topic.title
| most_used_mood_id
| message_count
```

I've been banging my head at this query for a good amount of time now without much progress. Counting the amount of messages is no problem, but calculating the most used emotion across all messages to a certain topic turned out to be quite tricky.

Leads into the correct direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desire results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, I will try to sanitise some data and provide it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get desired aggregates querying only `messages`:

```
select 
    id, topic_id, mood_id, 
    count(topic_id) over (partition by topic_id) message_count,
    count(mood_id) over (partition by topic_id, mood_id) mood_count
from message;
```

and use this as a derived table:

```
select distinct on (topic_id)
    t.id, 
    t.title,
    mood_id as most_used_mood_id,
    message_count
from (
    select 
        id, topic_id, mood_id, 
        count(topic_id) over (partition by topic_id) message_count,
        count(mood_id) over (partition by topic_id, mood_id) mood_count
    from message
    ) s
join 
    topic t on t.id = topic_id
order by 
    topic_id, mood_count desc;
```

Comment: After going through all the solution and trying different things, I found this one to be the best working. What kind of performance impact does this kind of statement (with `partition by` and `over`) have? Does it scale with large tables?

Comment: Generally [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html) are expensive. Simple `count(...)` with `group by...` should be 2-4 times faster than `count(...) over (partition...)`. However, window functions allow multiple aggregates (over different partitions) in one simple query in cases where *regular aggregates* need subqueries and complicated joins. Simple test on a table with 1 million rows shows about 4 s for this solution, while the query in another answer needs 88 s. I couldn't test the third query because of errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess based on your description.  It joins the messages, topics, and moods together and then aggregates at the topic level:

```
select distinct (t.topic_id) mtmo.*
from (select t.topic_id, t.title, m.mood_id, count(*) as cnt
      from message_topics m join
           topic t
           on mt.topic_id = t.topic_d join
           message_moods mo
           on mo.message_id = t.message_id and
              mo.message_id = mt.message_id
      group by t.topic_id, t.title
     ) mtmo
order by t.topic_id, cnt desc;
```

Comment: I don't think the condition `t.mood_id = mo.mood_id` is correct, it doesn't make sense to store the `mood_id` in the `topic` table because each topic can have multiple moods.

Comment: @sagi . . . Good catch.  That should be `message_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want the `mood_id` , no need to select from this table so:

```
SELECT tt.topic_id , tt.title, tt.mood_id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message mm WHERE mm.topic_id = tt.topic_id) as message_count
FROM (
    SELECT s.topic_id,s.title,s.mood_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.topic_id,s.title ORDER BY s.cnt DESC) as rnk
    FROM (
        SELECT t.topic_id,t.title,m.mood_id,count(*) as cnt
        FROM topic t
        INNER JOIN message m
         ON(m.topic_id = t.id)
        GROUP BY t.topic_id,t.title,m.mood_id) s ) tt
WHERE tt.rnk = 1
```